# How do I permanently assign my MIDI device to a specific channel or instrument in FL Studio?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, fl-studio

I have my AKAI MPKmini MIDI keyboard hooked up to FL Studio 12. When I focus one channel and play the keys, I hear that channel. But when I focus another channel, say, to adjust some settings, I want my keyboard to still play the first channel.

How can I create a permanent assignment between a MIDI device and a channel?

Some resources online mention a Fruity Wrapper setting. But what if you're not using Wrapper? Others mention a setting under the gear icon that no longer seems to exist in recent versions of FL Studio. Yet another post I found from 2006 outright says FL Studio doesn't support this feature.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very surprising, but FL Studio only *recently* added support for this feature in 2016, for FL Studio 12.3 ([release notes](http://forum.image-line.com/viewtopic.php?f=100&t=158809)):

> - Lock MIDI notes to Channels - Right-click a Channel Button and select Receive notes from.

When you do this correctly, you'll see a lock icon appear next to the channel name:

[image]

Something key for me was selecting "All" for the MIDI channel instead of a specific channel. I thought that assigning the input and output of the MPKmini2 to channel 10 in the MIDI settings (shown above as well) would allow me to specific lock channel 10, but it doesn't appear to work. I had to select "All".